# Obligations and recommendations of sacrificial slaughter?

Tags: dhabihah, eid-ul-adha, sacrifice

What are the obligatory conditions for sacrificial slaughter of animals to be valid? Also what are the Sunnah recommendations to follow?

I am asking about the details relevant to the actual act of slaughter and not for example the requirements regarding the animal such as its type, age and health etc.

Please provide Quran, Hadith or Fiqh references. I keep hearing of stuff like 'can't use a serrated knife', 'offer the animal water' and 'cut the four vessels of the throat', but I am unsure about the references for these or how these are derived.

Comment: This is rather too broad you should give your question more focus.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, the question seems clear. Slaughter requires "*a swift, deep incision to the throat with a very sharp knife, cutting the wind pipe, jugular veins and carotid arteries on both sides but leaving the spinal cord intact*" ([Dhabihah - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhabihah#:~:text=a%20swift,intact)). The Quran is consistent with, but doesn't explicitly state these specific requirements. The question is simply asking for references for where these requirements were first defined in writing.

Answer (score -1):

Sacrificial slaughter is known as "Qurbani" or "Udhiyah". It is a religious practice that involves the slaughter of an animal, usually a sheep, goat, cow, or camel, during the three days of Eid al-Adha, which is the major festival in the Islamic calendar. Here are some of the obligations and recommendations of sacrificial slaughter in Islam:

Obligation: Qurbani is obligatory upon every adult Muslim who is financially able to perform it. This means that a person who meets the criteria of being financially able, must offer a sacrifice on behalf of themselves or on behalf of those who are unable to do so.

Recommended: It is recommended that the animal being sacrificed is healthy, free from any diseases or defects, and has reached the appropriate age for slaughter.

Obligation: The animal should be slaughtered in the name of Allah, and the name of Allah should be pronounced at the time of slaughter.

Recommended: The person offering the sacrifice should perform the slaughter themselves if they are able to do so, or if not, they should be present at the time of slaughter.

Obligation: The meat of the animal should be divided into three parts. One part is for the person offering the sacrifice, one part is for the poor and needy, and one part is for family and friends.

Recommended: The meat should be distributed fresh, and not stored for long periods of time.

Obligation: The meat should be consumed within a reasonable time frame, and not wasted.

Recommended: It is recommended that the person offering the sacrifice fasts on the day of Eid al-Adha until after the sacrifice has been performed.

Obligation: If a person is unable to perform the sacrifice themselves, they can appoint someone else to do it on their behalf.

Overall, the purpose of Qurbani is to show gratitude to Allah for his blessings and to share those blessings with others by providing food for the poor and needy.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. Most of the claimed 'obligations' are not obligatory, and at least one of the recommendations is in fact obligatory.